# How to get Item Index in ArrayObject Class

Tags: php, arrayobject

I am implementing a class by inheriting PHP's ArrayObject class. But I don't find how to get the index of the array while iterating. I want to show both key and value

```
class TestArrayObject extends ArrayObject {
    public function displayAsTable() {
        $iterator = $this->getIterator();
        // Table
        echo '<table border="1">';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>Keys</th><th>Values</th>';
        echo '</tr>';
        while ($iterator->valid()) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$iterator->current().'</td><td>'.$iterator->current().'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            $iterator->next();
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }
}

$arrFruits = array('Apple','Banana', 'Mango');
$objArr = new TestArrayObject($arrFruits);
$objArr->displayAsTable();
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: And of course you don't want to use a manual. https://www.php.net/manual/en/iterator.key.php

Comment: Thanks bro it's working @u_mulder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the following line and it's working fine

`'<td>'.$iterator->key().'</td><td>'.$iterator->current().'</td>'`

For more info [see here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/iterator.key.php)